# How to rotate an object around a arbitrary point?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I want to rotate an UILabel around an arbitrary point in a circular manner, not a straight line. This is my code.The final point is perfect but it goes through a straight line between the initial and the end points.

```
- (void)rotateText:(UILabel *)label duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration degrees:(CGFloat)degrees {
    /* Setup the animation */
    [UILabel beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UILabel setAnimationDuration:duration];


    CGPoint rotationPoint = CGPointMake(160, 236);
    CGPoint transportPoint = CGPointMake(rotationPoint.x - label.center.x, rotationPoint.y - label.center.y);

    CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(label.transform, transportPoint.x, -transportPoint.y);
    CGAffineTransform t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(label.transform,DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees));
    CGAffineTransform t3 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(label.transform, -transportPoint.x, +transportPoint.y);

    CGAffineTransform t4 = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(t1, t2), t3);
    label.transform = t4;   

    /* Commit the changes */
    [UILabel commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: Check the blog post    http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Ask-Big-Nerd-Ranch-Rotating-an-iPhone-View-Around-a-Point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided to post my solution as an answer. It works fine accept it doesn't have the old solutions's curve animations (UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut), but I can sort that out.

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) (angle / 180.0 * M_PI)

- (void)rotateText:(UILabel *)label duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration degrees:(CGFloat)degrees {
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddArc(path,nil, 160, 236, 100, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0), DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees), YES);

    CAKeyframeAnimation *theAnimation;

    // animation object for the key path
    theAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    theAnimation.path=path;
    CGPathRelease(path);

    // set the animation properties
    theAnimation.duration=duration;
    theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO; 
    theAnimation.autoreverses = NO;
    theAnimation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAutoReverse;
    theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    [label.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"position"]; 
}
```

Comment: +1: Thanks for posting your solution! This will likely be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: same here thank you for oyur solution, another thing. Did you sort out easing? And i m trying to do something like UIScrollView but circular, any further help would be great.

Comment: At the end I used something else, but for easing you can create one main and one ease-in and ease-out rotations in a row.

Comment: Using a key-frame is overly complex for this situation. Have a look at my answer where I set a custom anchor point for the rotation. It works much like the code in your question except without the translate back and forth and concatenating multiple transforms.

Answer (score 9):

### You should set your own [`anchorPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint)

Its very much overkill to use a keyframe animation for what really is **a change of the anchor point**.

The anchor point is the point where all transforms are applied from, the default anchor point is the center. By moving the anchor point to (0,0) you can instead make the layer rotate from the bottom most corner. By setting the anchor point to something where *x* or *y* is outside the range 0.0 - 1.0 you can have the layer rotate around a point that lies outside of its bounds.

Please read the section about [Layer Geometry and Transforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html) in the Core Animation Programming Guide for more information. **It goes through this in detail with images to help you understand.**

---

#### EDIT: One thing to remember

The frame of your layer (which is also the frame of your view) is calculated using the position, bounds and anchor point. Changing the anchorPoint will change where your view appears on screen. You can counter this by re-setting the frame after changing the anchor point (this will set the position for you). Otherwise you can set the position to the point you are rotating to yourself. The [documentation (linked to above)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html) also mentions this.

---

### Applied to you code

The point you called "transportPoint" should be updated to calculate the difference between the rotation point and the lower left corner of the label divided by the width and height.

```
// Pseudocode for the correct anchor point
transportPoint = ( (rotationX - labelMinX)/labelWidth,
                   (rotationX - labelMinY)/labelHeight )
```

I also made the rotation point an argument to your method. The full updated code is below:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) (angle/180.0*M_PI)

- (void)rotateText:(UILabel *)label 
       aroundPoint:(CGPoint)rotationPoint 
          duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
           degrees:(CGFloat)degrees {

    /* Setup the animation */
    [UILabel beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UILabel setAnimationDuration:duration];

    // The anchor point is expressed in the unit coordinate
    // system ((0,0) to (1,1)) of the label. Therefore the 
    // x and y difference must be divided by the width and 
    // height of the label (divide x difference by width and 
    // y difference by height).
    CGPoint transportPoint = CGPointMake((rotationPoint.x - CGRectGetMinX(label.frame))/CGRectGetWidth(label.bounds),
                                         (rotationPoint.y - CGRectGetMinY(label.frame))/CGRectGetHeight(label.bounds));

    [label.layer setAnchorPoint:transportPoint];
    [label.layer setPosition:rotationPoint]; // change the position here to keep the frame 
    [label.layer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees), 0, 0, 1)];   

    /* Commit the changes */
    [UILabel commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`CAKeyframeAnimation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) is the right tool for this job. Most UIKit animations are between start and end points. The middle points are not considered. CAKeyframeAnimation allows you to define those middle points to provide a non-linear animation. You will have to provide the appropriate bezier path for your animation. You should look at [`this example`](http://watchingapple.com/2008/04/core-animation-creating-a-jack-in-the-box-with-cakeyframeanimation/) and the one's provided in the Apple documentation to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured out myself using CAKeyframeAnimation from the apple example.

Comment: I would say that setting the anchor point is the job for rotating around an arbitrary point. That is what an anchor point is. Using a key-frame animation is overly complicated and not really "the right told for this job"

Answer (score -1):

translate, rotate around center, translate back.

Comment: I think that's what I'm doing, but it doesn't go through a circular path. It's a straight line.